# How to check if function is Riemann integrable

Tags: real-analysis

I was given a piecewise function, which happens to be continuous on some interval. It asks me to prove that it's Riemann integrable. I know that continuous functions are Riemann integrable, but is there a way to prove it for some specific function (without using that theorem that continuous functions are Riemann integrable)?

Comment: A function is riemann integrable if and only if it has a countable number of discontinuities. This is proved in the starting parts of Lebesgue integration.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг ... No, not "if and only if".  But "if" is correct, together with boundedness, and may be enough for this question.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add boundedness. If the function is bounded and a.e continuous, then it is Riemann integrable.

Comment: @Darko Dekan: your question cannot be answered unless you supply some more information. Please edit the question to give more details about the function you are interested in.

Comment: I am sorry, may be it is a bit out of topic, but in the third edition of introduction of real analysis by prof.bartle section 7.3 (lebesgue integrability criterion), it is said that bounded function $f$ on $[a,b]$ is riemann integrable if and only if it is continuous almost everywhere (the measure of the set of discontinuity is 0), hence it means the discontinuity points do not have to be countable, right? if the discont set is cantor set (uncountable), the function is still riemann integrable, right?

Comment: You can always just take the general proof and adapt its steps to your example.